# When a bonded node loses a bet who gets the ETH?

Tags: security, proof-of-stake, casper, consensus

In Casper Proof-of-Stake, a validator needs to be a bonded node: it puts up a security deposit that can be lost if the validator misbehaves.

When a bonded node misbehaves, who receives the lost ETH?

Answer (score 2):

From a talk given by Vlad Zamfir **May 2016, lost bets and deposits will go to nobody.**  The reason is that if they were going to some accounts, this opens up attack vectors where attackers could control such accounts: an attacker could misbehave, "lose" their deposits, but pick up the deposits again.

Answer (score 1):

ETH is never getting lost, it will be associated to the `account/contract (address)` as long as the Ethereum Blockchain exists.

> For the people who lose the private-key/password will not have access to it.

If my answer is not enough, means i don't understand the **bonded node** part.

Comment: The question seems to refer to Proof-of-Stake, which is where the bonded node terminology comes from