# Casper betting details

Tags: casper, serenity

What incentive is there for validators to bet on a block early, rather than just waiting for the rest of the validators to reach consensus first? AFAICT, the [reward/penalty](https://github.com/ethereum/economic-modeling/tree/master/casper) is independent of when the bet was made. Wouldn't a validator get an optimal reward by betting after a block is finalized (or just before it's finalized, if that's disallowed).

Is there a penalty for changing a bet to have a lower probability or different block? Otherwise, I don't see how the penalty could ever apply, since validators would just change to a favorable bet later.

Since bets are made through a contract they must be included in blocks. Validators are also responsible for creating blocks. Is there ever an incentive for a validator to exclude a bet from a block, or does it not matter as long as the bet eventually makes it into a block? Is there an incentive for a validator to include a bet in a block? Do bets include transaction fees?

Cross-post from [/r/ethereum/](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5029iy/casper_betting/).

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5711/how-does-betting-on-a-block-work-in-casper

Answer (score 1):

You're right that in the economic-modeling simulation, the scoring rule there doesn't have a factor to increase the reward for early bets.

In a more recent implementation on the [pyethereum/serenity](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/serenity/ethereum/casper.se.py#L219-L226) branch, the scoring rule does incentivize earlier bets, with the factor `blockdiff * PER_BLOCK_BASE_COST`.

You may also be interested to see some some plots of the scoring rule payoffs here: [casper-scoring-rule.ipynb](https://gist.github.com/cdetrio/8c4fb2de96119fd3ae766c8f92789f89). Note that the plots there only show how the payoff varies with prediction accuracy, not how the payoff changes with respect to earliness or lateness.